# When do matrices have positive eigenvectors?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have a $3\times 3$ matrix and we know $\det(A) > 0$, so how can we prove that there is always a positive eigenvector?

Comment: What's a positive eigenvector?

Comment: I think the OP means a positive eigenvalue.

Comment: @ziyuang  an eigenvector which all elements are positive

Comment: Hint : the derminant is the product of the eigenvalues, with multiplicity.

Comment: @Farhad - with your definition "eigenvector with all elements are positive" the statement is not true: make an invertible matrix $P$ with exactly one strictly positive entry per column and all other entries negative, choose a diagonal matrix $D$ with distinct positive diagonal entries, then the matrix $PDP^{-1}$ is a counter example - the eigenvectors (up to scalar multiple) are the columns of $P$. On the other hand, as the other comments explain, your condition on the determinant means there is a positive eigenvalue.

Comment: @Farhad in my previous, I meant $D$ to have district *strictly* positive diagonal values...

Comment: @Farhad Is your matrix _non-negative_ (contains only non-negative entries) and _irreducible_?